# Axios request: xsrf token in cokkie and in header field

Tags: javascript, laravel, axios

I'm interested why axios post request contains xsrf token in cookie as well as in header field as in image:
[image]

For me it seems as doubling data and I can't find logic purpose of it. To check what happen with only XSRF token set in cookie I made request by fetch api. For this situation I'm getting 419 error from laravel (when i add XSRF field then everything is working). Why laravel cannot use XSRF from cookie and additionally needs XSRF set as field in header? There need to be logic explanation of it.